# Is my approach to performance testing in Linux environment correct?

Tags: linux, performance, testing

I want to do performance testing in a Linux environment for a C++ application. I need to measure the CPU & Memory usage of the application. This application is a multi-threaded application.

In this requirement I came across two Tools/Utilities (`sar` and `top`). My problem now is if I want to monitor CPU usage, by user, I can use the `top` utility for this but I'm not sure if this is available in the `sar` utility. If I'm wrong on my approach please direct me to the correct path on how to do performance testing in the Linux environment.

As an end note, I use PuTTY to login to the remote Linux machine though any GUI based tool will not help me.

Any help will be of great use to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `time` would properly do the whole job for you. Read the `man` page to avoid using a built-in `time` command.

Comment: Hi I decided on using pidstat command. I have got another issue now. I get -ve values for kB_rd/s and kB_wr/s. How do i manipulate the values listed from pidstat command.